# What does it mean "discharged return anticipated"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Forgive my poor understanding. I was just reading the document of `MDS`. Although every words can be recognized by myself. But when they combine together ,I totally had no idea about what does it mean. Please help to review it .Thanks.

```
discharge: to allow (someone) to leave a hospital, prison, etc.

anticipate:to think of (something that will or might happen in the future)
```

> When a resident is **discharged return anticipated** and the resident
>   returns to the facility within 30 days, the facility must copy the
>   previous RAI and transfer that copy to the new record. The15-month
>   requirement for maintenance of the RAI data must be adhered to.

note: RAI means Resident Assessment Instruments in the MDS 3.0. Thanks.

**My updated:**

I agree with Andrew's answer.

The original document explain some for these words in the following chapter.Thanks.

> **Discharge** refers to the date a resident leaves the facility. A day
>   begins at 12:00 a.m. and ends at 11:59 p.m. Regardless of whether
>   discharge occurs at 12:00 a.m. or 11:59 p.m., this date is considered
>   the actual date of discharge. There are two types of discharges –
>   **return anticipated and return not anticipated**. A Discharge assessment
>   is required with both types of discharges. Section 2.6 provides
>   detailed instructions regarding both discharge types.

Comment: Are you certain there's not a comma or dash between "discharged" and "return"?

Comment: Yes. These sentences is copied from the original document. Thanks.

Comment: hi Catija, Thanks for your review. Please refer the original document. https://www.cms.gov/Medicare/Quality-Initiatives-Patient-Assessment-Instruments/NursingHomeQualityInits/Downloads/MDS-3-RAI-Manual-v-1-1-2-R-Errata.pdf

Comment: Just open the document, search the text "discharged return anticipated" in the viewer like adobe reader, you will find many in the document. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like MDS [*jargon*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/jargon) that means "a resident/patient who has been discharged but expected to return (within a certain period of time)."  It is not standard English.

The book should have an explanation for what it means somewhere before this passage, otherwise it is expected you were taught this jargon during your training.

Comment: Unfortunately, These words just jump out suddenly when I read the document chapter by chapter or page by page. Thanks.